# Hive percentile() over () requires group by

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I'm going to calculate the percentile over all data where other data are calculated via `group by room_id` as following:

```
   select 
        distinct room_id,
        count(user_id) over (partition by room_id) as user_cnt,
        sum(price) over (partition by room_id) as price,
        percentile(cast(price as bigint),0.5) over () as price_median 
    from
        ods.ods_trade
    where day = '2017-08-08' and trade_status = 1
```

The above code can be run correctly in `SparkSQL` but in `hive` it says:

```
At least 1 group must only depend on input columns ... Expression not in GROUP BY key 'price'
```

`percentile() over()` also returns 1 value, so why does this issue happen and how to address it? Any help will be appreciated..

e.g.:
The data is :

```
room  user price(consume)
  a    u1    1
  a    u1    5
  a    u2    3
  b    u1    2
  b    u3    4
  c    u4    6
  c    u4    7
```

Expected results:

```
  room_id  user_cnt   price  price_median
    a        2         8         4
    b        2         6         4
    c        1         13        4
```

Comment: remove `distinct`..it doesn't work when using window functions on Hive.

Comment: @vkp thanks, but the same error after removing `distinct`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says price is not in group by. Below query should work:

```
select room, count(distinct user_id) , sum(price),
price_median from (
SELECT room, user_id, price, 
percentile(cast(price as bigint),0.5) OVER () as price_median
FROM ods.ods_trade
GROUP BY room, USER_id, price
  )k1
 group by room, price_median
```

Note: the column names might slightly vary.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This does work but the result is not expected.

Comment: Please update your question with sample of input data and what you are expecting as output.

Comment: @superz edited the actual query to fetch the expected output.